# How to insert special characters/superscript into SQL Server using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, character

I have a web application using entity framework to read and update a database. The data being entered into the database can contain a range of different characters such as superscript and characters like this: β.

They are not saving into the database correctly - they are displaying like as follows: cm3.

The column is already a NVarChar and the database collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

I expect the text to be exactly the same as what was entered.

Comment: Showing your code will help here. (I suspect a lack of parametrisation.)

Comment: This is an example of the code I've used:  newRecord.abstract = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBx.Text) ? null : txtBox.Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the Unicode method
Example:= SELECT cast(N'Abhinandᵀᴹ' as nvarchar) AS Sample

nvarchar converts string into Unicode so a way to use a superscript is to putting it into a Unicode

note use the capital N before your string or text, otherwise it won't show